# Сколько места занимают индексы таблицы InnoDB в mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть заполненная данными таблица InnoDB в mySQL. Для таблицы заданы несколько индексов.

1) Как узнать сколько места (в МБайтах, например) занимают эти индексы и каждый по отдельности?

2) mySQL старается хранить индексы таблиц целиком в памяти сервера? Или больше внимания уделяется кэшу последний запросов?

Последний вопрос интересует применительно к тому, стоит ли увеличить память на сервере с 16ГБ до 32ГБ в надежде, что в память будут загружены индексы таблиц по максимуму, для большего быстродействия. Сейчас кэш занимает всю свободную память - 15ГБ. И я не знаю, забита ли память кэшом данными последних/частых запросов или индексами.

Comment: *стоит ли увеличить память на сервере с 16ГБ до 32ГБ* Памяти много не бывает, тем более на SQL-сервере. Есть возможность? увеличивайте.

Comment: `Mysql workbench` умеет показывать размер индекса (Правый клик по имени таблицы -> Table inspector)